# Show images asynchronouly in UITableView from server in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, asynchronous, nsurlcache

When I try to fetch the images in UITableView using NSURL
`UIImage image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/mobile/abc.jpg]]];`
my application get freezes until the images loaded. Also when I scroll the table it get images from the server again and scroll get stuck for some time.
I know this is happening because of downloading images synchronously from server.
Is there any solution so that I can download the image asynchronously from server and store it locally or in cache so that when table scrolls it did not get images again from server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading) by enormego. Works just like UIImage (and caches images) but lets you load from HTTP asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks Keller for your reply. I will check this tomorrow, but from documentation its look that it will do my work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class which leverages `NSURLConnection` and it's various Asynchronous methods to load your images in the background and then have a callback to display it in the cell.

However, there are some excellent libraries which do exactly what you've described. [HJCache](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/) is one i've used and recommend for this sole purpose

Comment: Thanks Suhail for you quick reply. I will look in to HJCache libraries. It is very helpful if you provide me some piece of code how to integrate it with with table view and cache images so that table scrolling get smoother.

Comment: There is a section on the webpage titled 'How to Use HJCache' which describes everything you need to do for it to work. There is also a Demo App which works really smoothly on the Github Page: https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache